# Is there any way by which you can substitute a variable with its value in a function's attribute in Python?

Tags: python, tkinter

I wanted to know if there is any way we can substitute a variable in a functions attribute in Python. For example, consider this code:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox

def message(type, title, text):
    msg = messagebox.type(title, text)

message("showerror", "Error!", "Error in processing!")
```

In the fifth line of the above code, can I replace the variable "type" with its value? If yes, how?

(I know we can't replace a string in the attribute even if it was possible, but since I don't know what to replace it with, I just put in it as a value. Please excuse it.)

Comment: Try `getattr(messagebox, type)(title, text)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get a module/class's attribute by using the built in `getattr` function. For example look at this:

```py
>>> import tkinter as tk
>>> getattr(tk, "Button")
<class 'tkinter.Button'>
```

and this:

```py
>>> import tkinter as tk
>>> var = "Label"
>>> getattr(tk, var)
<class 'tkinter.Label'>
```

So you can change your code to:

```py
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox

def message(type, title, text):
    msg = getattr(messagebox, type)(title, text)
    return msg

message("showerror", "Error!", "Error in processing!")
```

Comment: btw I didn't add this in my answer but there is also a `setattr` built in function

Comment: Yes I found it while I was searching about the details of 'getattr()'. Anyways, thank you for informing :)